# Can't start Portal Express 7 on Windows 2003

Tags: installation, websphere-portal

I have a Windows 2003 SP2 Virtual Box guest in which I'm trying to install Portal Express 7.

During the installation there's a prompt that said that the Server couldn't start and I have to that manually. When I try to start it using startServer.bat I get every time this message:

```
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log,SytemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/profiles\default\logs\server1 should contain failure information.

ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with server: WebSphere_Portal;probable error executing WASService.exe: com.ibm.ws.management.tools.ProblemInWASServiceException: ADMU7711E: Unexpected exception associated with WASService.exe: exitCode = -1 during processing of server with name: WebSphere_Portal
```

In the logs I only found `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/ibm/ffdc/impl/EmptyProvider$EmptyFfdc` and several `verbosegc.txt` files. Have anyone succeeded in installing IBM WP 7 on Windows 2003?

PS: My problem is very similar to [this DeveloperWorks post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14853422).

Comment: That screams [PMR](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Open_service_request/Software/Software_support_(general)) to me

Answer (score 0):

If you can start it manually but not through Windows Service, perhaps something got corrupted into the service definition. No problem, you may very simply remove it (WASService.exe -remove servicename in AppServer/bin directory ), and then add it again

I use a syntax like this one

wasservice -add "Cluster1_server1" -serverName "Cluster1_server1" -profilePath "D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01" -wasHome "D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer" -stopArgs " -username youradmin-password yourpassword" -encodeParams

or you may also insert username and password into soap.client.props, so you don't need to change it all the times.